# Dynamically filling ListView with an image and a string

Tags: c#, wpf, image, listview

I would like to fill my ListView with do aligned elements, a little icon (either a confirm mark or a cross) and a string which contains the result of a question (Right / Wrong, that's why icon).

```
daInserire = new ListViewItem();
daInserire.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGreen);
daInserire.Content = "Giusto: "+ straniero.Text + " = " + vocItaliano[current];
daInserire.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
daInserire.FontSize = 18;
//...
listViewConInfo.Items.Add(daInserire);
```

This works perfectly, I'd like to add before the string, on the same line an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using WPF, so you'll need to create a StackPanel for your Content property and add the Image and a Label to that StackPanel.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that, but... How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
 ListView lV = new listView(); 
 ListViewItem Item = new ListViewItem(); 
 WrapPanel wrap = new WrapPanel(); 
 Image image = new image();
 image.Source = <<yourSource>>;
 Label label = new Label();
 label.Content = "W/E you want";
 wrap.Children.Add(image);
 wrap.Children.Add(label);
 Item.Content = wrap;
 lV.Items.Add(Item);
```